# Finding eigenvectors of a 3x3 matrix with a root of multiplicity 3

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\2&2&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}
I know that the only eigenvalue is 1 with multiplicity 3

I solved for the first eigenvalue and got \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}

How do I find the other two?  I know they are \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix}1/2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
but when I do $(A-\lambda I)v_2 = v_1$, I get the system of equations $2x + y -z = 1$, 
$y -z =1$.  I don't see how that gives the second eigenvector.

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of generalized eigenvectors and methods of finding those? Your particular example requires two generalized eigenvectors and there are many such examples on MSE. For example, http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/sg/classnotes1.pdf

Comment: What makes you think there are $3$ independent eigenvectors ? If there were, then $A$ would be diagonalizable, with only eigenvalue $1$, which would mean $A$ would be unity matrix, which it is definitely not :-) Your system for kernel of $A-\lambda I$ has two equations, so the eigenspace should have dimension $1$.

Comment: Here is an example where **algebraic multiplicity** and **geometric multiplicity** are different. Those are important to know at least probably later course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is just to solve the system. The system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
2x+y-z=1,\\
\qquad y-z=1
\end{cases}
$$
has the solution
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1+t\\t
\end{bmatrix},\quad t\in\Bbb R.
$$
Now take $t=0$.

The second vector is obtained similarly: solve
$$
\begin{cases}
2x+y-z=1,\\
\qquad y-z=0
\end{cases}
$$
to get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1/2\\-t\\t
\end{bmatrix},\quad t\in\Bbb R
$$
and set $t=0$.

P.S. Those other two vectors are not eigenvectors. They are called *generalized* eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Linear Algebra tool like in MATLAB, or a libraries for programming languages, like NumPy with Python or MathNet Numerics with C#, you can find out that the eigenvectors calculated by these tools are:

[0, 0, 0]
[(√2)/2, (√2)/2, (√2)/2]
[(√2)/2, (√2)/2, (√2)/2]

The eigenvalues are as stated:

(1,0)
(1,0)
(1,0)

1 of multiplicity 3.

We should bear in mind that eigenvalues could be complex numbers.

Comment: Please use MathJax for mathematical equations and expressions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @jvdhooft: Thanks a lot for the advice on MathJax, will do!